# yum broken when I interrupt updating nss-softokn-freebl-3.36.0-5.el7_5.x86_64

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, yum

My system is centos7.

```
[root@centos7 caiyiheng]# uname -a
Linux centos7 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 6 11:36:42 UTC 2015 
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My system run in a virtualbox.

When I run the cmd `yum -y update`, and press `ctrl+c` while yum is updateing something. after that I found I can't use yum or rpm anymore. when I input yum or rpm it show as:

```
[root@centos7 caiyiheng]# yum
error: Failed to initialize NSS library
error: no dbpath has been set
error: cannot open Packages database in /%{_dbpath}
CRITICAL:yum.main:

Error: rpmdb open failed
[root@centos7 caiyiheng]# rpm
error: Failed to initialize NSS library
```

most yum or rpm command can't work, such as `yum install`,`yum clean all` even `yum --help`.

I check `/var/log/yum.log`, it show as:

```
[root@centos7 caiyiheng]# tail -f /var/log/yum.log
Sep 21 05:53:21 Installed: wget-1.14-15.el7_4.1.x86_64
Sep 21 05:53:21 Installed: lsof-4.87-5.el7.x86_64
Sep 21 05:53:22 Installed: net-tools-2.0-0.22.20131004git.el7.x86_64
Sep 26 17:28:11 Updated: libgcc-4.8.5-28.el7_5.1.x86_64
Sep 26 17:28:12 Installed: 1:grub2-common-2.02-0.65.el7.centos.2.noarch
Sep 26 17:28:13 Installed: 1:grub2-pc-modules-2.02-0.65.el7.centos.2.noarch
Sep 26 17:28:13 Installed: firewalld-filesystem-0.4.4.4-14.el7.noarch
Sep 26 17:28:14 Updated: tzdata-2018e-3.el7.noarch
Sep 26 17:28:14 Updated: ncurses-base-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.noarch
Sep 26 17:28:15 Updated: nss-softokn-freebl-3.36.0-5.el7_5.x86_64
```

and I search in google for a whole day, found lots of solutions may like my problem, I tried them but nothing happen.

such as

- https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/rpm-yum-error-no-dbpath-has-been-set-4175539473/
- https://serverfault.com/questions/866294/error-failed-to-initialize-nss-library

I even download the rpm https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-updates-x86_64/nss-softokn-freebl-3.36.0-5.el7_5.x86_64.rpm.html

and `rpm2cpio nss-softokn-freebl-3.36.0-5.el7_5.x86_64.rpm | cpio -idmv` and copy ./usr/lib or lib64 or ./etc to /usr/lib /usr/lib64 /etc, but all of that can't solve my problem.

Someone mentioned that yum has a problem with chroot (https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=14767) but it doesn't match my situation, I even tried that, but nothing happen.

Comment: Can you check `rpm -qa |grep nss` and [edit] your question to post the results please (if it will let you run that)

Comment: no, can't run rpm -qa,show the same error,maybe I need to reinstall my system.

Comment: Have you tried running that `rpm2cpio` command at the root of the machine? That would automatically dump the required files. Maybe try it with the _previous_ version noted in `yum.log`

Answer (score 0):

I just experience the same issue. it took me hours to find the issue and solve it. my case is interrupt the `yum update` and the last `yum.log` record is just like you

```
Oct 22 19:04:36 Updated: 1:grub2-pc-modules-2.02-0.65.el7.centos.2.noarch
Oct 22 19:04:36 Updated: tzdata-2018e-3.el7.noarch
Oct 22 19:04:37 Updated: bash-4.2.46-30.el7.x86_64
Oct 22 19:04:37 Updated: nss-softokn-freebl-3.36.0-5.el7_5.x86_64
```

I searched and tried the all the solutions but no luck just like you. then I read the rpm source and found in the `rpm/rpmio/digest_nss.c`

```
#if HAVE_NSS_INITCONTEXT
    PRUint32 flags = (NSS_INIT_READONLY|NSS_INIT_NOCERTDB|
              NSS_INIT_NOMODDB|NSS_INIT_FORCEOPEN|
              NSS_INIT_NOROOTINIT|NSS_INIT_OPTIMIZESPACE);
    _nss_ctx = NSS_InitContext(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, flags);
    if (_nss_ctx == NULL) {
#else
    if (NSS_NoDB_Init(NULL) != SECSuccess) {
#endif
        rpmlog(RPMLOG_ERR, _("Failed to initialize NSS library\n"));
        rc = -1;
    } else {
        _crypto_initialized = 1;
    }
    sigaction(SIGPIPE, &oact, NULL);
    }

    /* Register one post-fork handler per process */
    if (_new_process) {
    if (pthread_atfork(NULL, NULL, at_forkchild) != 0) {
        rpmlog(RPMLOG_WARNING, _("Failed to register fork handler: %m\n"));
    }
    _new_process = 0;
    }
    return rc;
}
```

then I tried with code like this to verify

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <nss.h>

int main() {
    NSSInitContext * _nss_ctx = NULL;
    printf("hello world!\n");
    PRUint32 flags = (NSS_INIT_READONLY|NSS_INIT_NOCERTDB|
                      NSS_INIT_NOMODDB|NSS_INIT_FORCEOPEN|
                      NSS_INIT_NOROOTINIT|NSS_INIT_OPTIMIZESPACE);
    _nss_ctx = NSS_InitContext(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, flags);
    if(_nss_ctx == NULL){
      printf("Error");
    }else{
      printf("OK");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and got the `NSS_InitContext` is not referenced. ~~ so it is clear the lib version is not match

wget both 
`nss-3.36.0-7.el7_5.x86_64.rpm` and 
`nspr-4.13.1-1.0.el7_3.x86_64.rpm` (my system is centos7)

using `rpm2cpio *rpm | cpio -idmv` to extract the file and copy to /usr

run `rpm` still got the error

```
version `NSSUTIL_3.31' not found (required by /lib64/libnss3.so)
```

wget the nss-util-3.36.0-1.el7_5.x86_64.rpm and do a more `rpm2cpio and copy`

then everything get ok ~ hope this can help you

Comment: thx all the same though I have already reinstall my centos7,maybe next time I will try your solution.